# What is the idiomatic way to set class/instance variables in a class definition in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, idioms

For instance, in Python, I can create a class like this:

```
class foo(object):
    bar = 'x'
    def __init__(self, some_value):
        self.some_attr = some_value
```

...where bar is a class attribute and some_attr is an instance attribute.  What is the idiomatic way to do things like this in Ruby?

Comment: should be class foo instead of def foo...

Comment: Doh!  It's amazing that nobody caught it until just now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Foo

  @@bar = 'x'
  attr_accessor :some_attr

  def initialize(some_value)
    self.some_attr = some_value
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much what weppos wrote, but I would use the @-sigil for the instance variable (it's common practice).

Like:

```
def initialize(some_value)
    @some_attr = some_value
end
```

Also, I would not name the class "Foo", but that has nothing do to with Ruby.

Comment: I wouldn't name it Foo either, but it's always the first thing that springs to mind when giving examples like these.  :-)

Comment: Yes, I get some of the reasons for foo/bar etc... It's good to have common names for examples I guess, I just don't like them because they are "ugly" names :P. Spam and eggs from the Python community are, if nothing else, funnier :)